# Android Send mail Application

Tags: android

```
     I use the following send mail application  in android from
```

[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-ap/2033124#2033124)

```
    and got the  warning 
    10-07 17:58:22.762: INFO/SSLSocketFactory(925): 
    Using factory org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl@4007ed70 
  10-07 17:58:23.063: DEBUG/NativeCrypto(925): SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 is set
    10-07 17:58:23.573: INFO/global(925): Default buffer size used in         
   BufferedOutputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k   
   buffer     is required.

   10-07 17:58:23.573: INFO/global(925): Default buffer size used in 
    BufferedInputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k   
   buffer  is required.

   10-07 17:58:24.172: INFO/global(925): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
```

please Help me to find solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set the buffer size (the default is `8K`).

I  use something like:

```
//( set to 2K in this case)
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inputstream, 2*1024);
```

Then you will not get that Android warning and save memory too I hope.

Comment: Hi, In the android sendmail application, where do i need to add this code fragment ? im confused :S